# Is there simple way to encode json data in Django?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I will get data like this from OpenID provider:

```
{"identity":"http:\/\/admin.lol.com\/","provider":"http:\/\/lol.com\/server\/",
"name":{"full_name":"\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439"},
"nickname":"admin","email":"admin@lol.ru","gender":"M","dob":"1985-01-31"}
```

How to get this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django by default bundles the simplejson library at django.utils.simplejson (http://undefined.org/python/#simplejson).  Additionally if you're using python 2.6 or better you can simply `import json` and you will get the builtin json libraryhttp://docs.python.org/library/json.html.  There are also a multitude of other python json libraries, but those two should be vastly more than adequate.

Once you have decided on a library to use you will simply need to pass your json string to the decoder of that library.  For the builtin json library that would be:

```
data = json.loads(your_json_string_here)
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html